# Как функцией определить, первая из них больше или равняется другой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть 2 даты в формате

15.12.2021

16.12.2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  const [d, m, y] = date.split('.');
  return Date.parse(`${y}-${m}-${d}`);
}

console.log(parseDate('15.12.2021') >= parseDate('16.12.2021'));
```

Comment: спасибо, а можно получить в отдельную переменную, если условие верно - 16.12.2021 + 1 день? тоесть вторая дата + 1 день

Comment: `parseDate('16.12.2021') + 1000 * 3600 * 24`

Comment: именно в формате 16.12.2021